# How do I determine which html elements are using a font?

Tags: html, css, fonts, frontend

I'm working on a website that downloads about a dozen fonts and I'm trying to figure out where they're being used. I know that the page will only download a font once it's being applied to actual rendered text - I just can't tell where that text is on the page. Does anyone know any methods or tools for figuring out where a font is being applied on a large web page?

Chrome dev tools were helpful in tracking down the fonts being downloaded by the page - but how do I track down which elements are using these fonts?

Comment: This could conceivably be done with JS, maybe; but have you made any attempts at all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Getting all elements grouped by computed `font-family` style**

If you're interested in an *extremely* rudimentary solution, try this:

```
var fonts = {};

document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(element) {
    var fontFamily = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('font-family');

    fonts[fontFamily] = fonts[fontFamily] || [];

    fonts[fontFamily].push(element);
});

console.log(fonts);
```

It'll group the page's elements by computed font-family and then log them to the console.

At least on Chrome Dev Tools, hovering the logged element will highlight it in the page.

Note that "computed font-family" doesn't mean the element was actually *rendered* using that font-family, only that it's the font computed from the CSS (or lack thereof, in the case of default fonts).

**Getting all elements whose computed `font-family` includes font X**

Here's a similar approach, targeting a specific font:

```js
function getElementsUsingFont(fontName) {
  var elements = [];

  document.querySelectorAll('*').forEach(function(element) {
    var fontFamily = window.getComputedStyle(element).getPropertyValue('font-family');

    if (fontFamily.includes(fontName)) {
      elements.push(element);
    }
  });

  return elements;
}

console.log(getElementsUsingFont('monospace'));
```

```html
<span style="font-family: monospace">Dragons!</span>
```

Unfortunately, this will capture elements that include the given font name *anywhere* in its list of possible fonts. For example"

```
span {
     font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, ChuckNorris, monospace, 'Comic Sans';
}
```

The above snippet would capture any element with that style because "monospace" is in the list. You could tinker with the conditions to `push` the element to try to choose more carefully (regex maybe?).

Comment: This feels like a cheat code! This is not only what I was looking for - it's a lot better than what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewKirchmyer you bet! Added a variation which might be useful in a slightly different way.

Comment: This is so amazing. It's beautiful 