# How to list @font-face using CSS or JS

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have an icon element which is defined as

```
<span class="sap-icon icon-locked"></span>

.sap-icon:before {
  font-family: "SAP-icons";
}
.icon-locked {
  content: "\e153";
}
```

I want to check where the custom font "SAP-icons" is defined.
I have removed all font face in my code, but the icon still exists.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "SAP-icons";
  src: font-url("SAP-icons.woff2") format("woff2");
}
```

Is there a way to list the `@font-face` of "SAP-icons"?

I can list font using `window.getComputedStyle(temp1,':before').font`:

[image]

Is there anything like `window.getComputedStyle(temp1,':before').font-face`?

Also, I have checked the Computed CSS in chrome dev tools, no information for font face, so how do I know where this icon font is defined?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I determine which html elements are using a font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50766569/how-do-i-determine-which-html-elements-are-using-a-font)

Comment: Nope, I want to check `@font-face` instead of `font-family`

Comment: After troubleshooting, I found the reason why the font still exists after I removed all the `@font-face` definitions is that I installed this font on my machine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fonts tab in firefox devtools that list @font-face rule. https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/page_inspector/how_to/edit_fonts/index.html#the-fonts-tab

Answer (score 0):

You can use **fontFamily** instead of font-family in JavaScript, to see where the icon font is defined.

Like this:

```
console.log(window.getComputedStyle(temp1,':before').fontFamily);
// SAP-icons
```

Comment: I want to check `@font-face` instead of `font-family`, the accepted answer solves my problem, thanks~